# Having Trouble pasting a dynamic range VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and paste a dynamic range within one sheet. I am able to copy my data, but it will not paste, giving me "run time error 1004: Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed"

code here:

```
Range("A19:B" & Range("A19").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
Range("O19:P").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

Can someone help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line should be:

```
Range("O19").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

But a quicker method, when only wanting the values, is to skip the clipboard and assign the values directly:

```
Range("O19:P" & Range("A19").End(xlDown).Row).Value = Range("A19:B" & Range("A19").End(xlDown).Row).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("A19:B" & Range("A19").End(xlDown).Row).Copy
Range("O19").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

All you have to do is use O19 instead of O19:P

Excel automatically pastes value in the area from the referred cell.